# Return an array of a struct in c++, and pass this array to another method?

Tags: c++, arrays, function, struct

I need to return an array of structs and then pass this array to another method for printing.

Here is my .h file:

```
#include <string>
#include "COMMON_TYPES.h"

#pragma once
#pragma pack(push, 1)

 class ARS_HR_LINE_1
{
public:
    struct ARS_HR_LINE_1_ALL
    {
        //Countre
        int     Counter
        float       Inner_Rate_FB_Fine;
        float           Inner_Rate_FB_Cross;
        float           Inner_Rate_FB_Roll;
        float           IMU_Yaw;
    };

    u16 img [1][616];

    //Methods
    ARS_HR_LINE_1::ARS_HR_LINE_1_ALL  *Process_HR_ARS_Line_1(); 
    void                              Print_HR_Line_1(FILE* fptr, int counter, ARS_HR_LINE_1::ARS_HR_LINE_1_ALL* h);    // Print High Rate Line 1
    };

#pragma pack(pop)
```

The .cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "ARS_HR_LINE_1.h"
#include "COMMON_TYPES.h"

using namespace std;

ARS_HR_LINE_1::ARS_HR_LINE_1_ALL * ARS_HR_LINE_1::Process_HR_ARS_Line_1()
{
    ARS_HR_LINE_1::ARS_HR_LINE_1_ALL h[60];

    for(int i=0;i<60;++i)
    {
        h[i].Counter = (ARS_HR_LINE_1::img[0][i*10 + 0] << 16) + ARS_HR_LINE_1::img[0][i*10 + 1];

        u32 inner_rate_fb_fine = (ARS_HR_LINE_1::img[0][i*10 + 2] << 16) + ARS_HR_LINE_1::img[0][i*10+3];
        h[i].Inner_Rate_FB_Fine =*reinterpret_cast<float*>(&inner_rate_fb_fine);

        u32 inner_rate_fb_cross = (ARS_HR_LINE_1::img[0][i*10+4] << 16) + ARS_HR_LINE_1::img[0][i*10+5];
        h[i].Inner_Rate_FB_Cross =*reinterpret_cast<float*>(&inner_rate_fb_cross);

        u32 inner_rate_fb_roll = (ARS_HR_LINE_1::img[0][i*10+6] << 16) + ARS_HR_LINE_1::img[0][i*10+7];
        h[i].Inner_Rate_FB_Roll =*reinterpret_cast<float*>(&inner_rate_fb_roll);

        u32 imu_yaw = (ARS_HR_LINE_1::img[0][i*10+8] << 16) + ARS_HR_LINE_1::img[0][i*10+9];
        h[i].IMU_Yaw =*reinterpret_cast<float*>(&imu_yaw);
    }
    return h;
}

void ARS_HR_LINE_1::Print_HR_Line_1(FILE* fptr, int counter, ARS_HR_LINE_1::ARS_HR_LINE_1_ALL *h)
{
    ARS_HR_LINE_1::ARS_HR_LINE_1_ALL temp;

    temp.Counter = 0;
    temp.Inner_Rate_FB_Fine = 0;
    temp.Inner_Rate_FB_Cross = 0;
    temp.Inner_Rate_FB_Roll = 0;
    temp.IMU_Yaw = 0;

    //tempArr[i] = *(h+i);
    fprintf(fptr, "************************************************************\n");
    fprintf(fptr, "******************IMAGE NUMBER %d ***************************\n", counter);


fprintf(fptr, "*********************LINE 1**********************************\n");

for(int i=0;i<60;++i)
{   
    temp = *(h+i);
    //Counter and Filler - 4 bytes
    fprintf(fptr, "Counter[%d]                                      : %u\n", temp.Counter, i);

    //Rate FB
    fprintf(fptr, "Inner_Rate_FB_Fine[%d]                           : %12.20f\n", temp.Inner_Rate_FB_Fine, i);
    fprintf(fptr, "Inner_Rate_FB_Cross[%d]                          : %12.20f\n", temp.Inner_Rate_FB_Cross, i);
    fprintf(fptr, "Inner_Rate_FB_Roll[%d]                           : %12.20f\n", temp.Inner_Rate_FB_Roll, i);

    //IMU_Yaw
    fprintf(fptr, "IMU_Yaw[%d]                                      : %12.20f\n", temp.IMU_Yaw, i);
}
}
```

and then in the main I use the following:

```
ARS_HR_LINE_1::ARS_HR_LINE_1_ALL* h;
ARS_HR_LINE_2::ARS_HR_LINE_2_ALL* h2;

h = ARS_HR_DEBUG_DATA.Process_HR_ARS_Line_1();
h2 = ARS_HR_DEBUG_DATA2.Process_HR_ARS_Line_2();

ARS_HR_DEBUG_DATA.Print_HR_Line_1(tassTxtFptr, i, h);
ARS_HR_DEBUG_DATA2.Print_HR_Line_2(tassTxtFptr, i, h2);
```

where tassTxtFptr is a pointer to a text file.

my Process_HR_ARS_Line_1 seems to be working properly, and when I bring up the array in visual studio, prior to returning it, all of the values look correct. When I go to print my information, I get a lot of gibberish, mixed with the correct values. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Use `std:vector`, write `c++` code, not `c`-like code.

Comment: Pay attention to your compiler warnings. It should be telling you that you shouldn't return a pointer to a local variable.

Comment: `I need to return an array of structs and then pass this array to another method for printing.` Nah, you don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your declaration `ARS_HR_LINE_1::ARS_HR_LINE_1_ALL h[60];` (a local variable) is allocating the space for your array within the stack frame of the call to `Process_HR_ARS_Line_1()`. After your program leaves that method, the memory allocated on the stack for that array is no longer valid. Accessing this memory is undefined behavior.

By returning `h`, that array decays to a pointer and you are effectively returning a pointer to the invalid memory space on the stack.

How do you get around this? Use `std::vector`. Alternatively you could allocate the array on the heap using `new`, but since this is C++ you should use the facilities available to you to simplify your memory management.

Comment: Thank you! I changed it to using vectors, and it was so much easier. I haven't touched c++ in quite a while, and so I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 4):

The array h ceases to exist when the `Process` function ends, so the pointer points to where it used to be (and who knows what info is there now?).  I would suggest declaring the array in main and passing it to the function to be filled, or using one of the STL containers like `vector`.

Comment: A grudging +1 for the least awful answer. At least there's no useless talk about "stack" or terrible recommendations like "new" in here.

Comment: @KerrekSB What's wrong with talking about the stack, or `new`? The issue is due directly to the asker's  lack of care while using stack variables, and the sooner he/she learns about them the better, IMHO. These are important things in C++!

Comment: @Keeler: Careless use of `new` (specifically, juggling raw pointers to things allocated with `new` and hoping someone deletes them correctly) is a recipe for memory leaks and other disasters. You should always use RAII to manage dynamic resources reliably. I've no idea why talking about the stack might be considered useless; that seems very relevant to the issue of returning a pointer to a local variable.

Comment: I'm not Kerrek, but I didn't talk about the stack b/c I don't see what it gains over just talking about "local" variables (although I didn't actually use that word either) or just scope in general.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: The "stack" is a completely irrelevant implementation detail that just clutters up the mind. The point is that the pointer outlives the pointee, and that's what's important, and that's what you need to consider. The more consise and to the point, the better. And teaching `new` to beginners is a crime in its own right.

Comment: @KerrekSB: The "stack" is also a useful model for how automatic objects are created and destroyed as the program enters and leaves their scopes; understanding that is fundamental to understanding *why* the pointer outlives the pointee. (And I fully agree with you about `new`).

Comment: @MikeSeymour: I find the notion of a "scope" much more useful: You enter and leave scopes. Names are declared inside scopes and live as long as the scope does. Seems simple and teachable to me; I've never seen anyone confused when you explain it like that.

Comment: @KerrekSB: But when you call a function, you leave the caller's scope; yet its automatic variables are still alive, and accessible if you have a reference to them. If we're discussing object lifetimes, the dynamic structure of scopes through which the program has reached the current scope is more relevant than the static structure of which names are in scope; and that dynamic structure is a stack.

Answer (score 1):

```
 ARS_HR_LINE_1::ARS_HR_LINE_1_ALL h[60];
 return h;
```

You are returning a pointer to a local variable. It gets destroyed when function exits. You should create the array using new, and taking care to delete the pointer after using it

Comment: Or return `std::vector`, so the poor user doesn't have to jump through hoops to call the function safely.

Comment: Yes, using a container will make thinks easier. and using streams instead of FILE* . As @StoryTeller points, that's is a bit C-like C++

Answer (score 1):

You're allocating the array `h` on the stack. When you return from the function, the `h` leaves scope and is freed from the stack. You return a pointer to `h` which is no longer valid!

Either use `new` to allocate space on the heap that will exist outside the function (don't forget to `delete` it later!) or use STL `vector`.

Answer (score 1):

You are allocating the array inside the method on the stack, which means that it is going to go out of scope as soon as your method is finished (thats why it is filled with carbage). Try allocating it on the heap instead, or if you still want to allocate it on the stack try using call-by-reference.
Call-by-reference can be achieved by changing your code as follows:

```
void Process_HR_ARS_Line_1(ARS_HR_LINE_1_ALL* h);
```

Your main can now look like this:

```
ARS_HR_LINE_1::ARS_HR_LINE_1_ALL h[60];

ARS_HR_DEBUG_DATA.Process_HR_ARS_Line_1(&h);

ARS_HR_DEBUG_DATA.Print_HR_Line_1(tassTxtFptr, i, &h);
```

To allocate your list on the heap you can do as follows (Its allways important to remember to use `delete[]` when you allocate something on the heap):

```
ARS_HR_LINE_1::ARS_HR_LINE_1_ALL* h = new ARS_HR_LINE_1::ARS_HR_LINE_1_ALL[60];

delete[] h;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for being so detailed. I appreciate your help!